# Create collection of products that match a query within/grouped by product groups

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is a complicated one to explain...

I am trying get a collection of `product_groups`, with their `products` that match a query on a `product.attributes` relationship

Product Group A

- Product 1 (matches queried value)
- Product 2 (matches queried value)

Product Group B

- Product 3 (matches queried value)

Product Group C

- Product 4 (matches queried value)

Using the following code, I have the correct product_groups, but instead of just getting the matching products, I am getting all products within to that product_group

```
$product_groups = ProductGroup::with('products')
    ->whereHas('products.attributes', function($query) use ($value) {
        $query->where('value', $value);
    })
    ->get();
```

The goal is to show a table for each product_group that lists the products that match the queried value (along with other information). I need to be able to use attributes from both the product_group and products in my blade file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're not query the correct thing. The whereHas will just check that if a productGroup has a product->attrubtes that match the query then the productGroup will be returend and then with() is just loading all the products onto that group

You need to update the with to something like this

```
$product_groups = ProductGroup::with('products', function($query){
    ->whereHas('attributes', function($query) use ($value) {
        $query->where('value', $value);
      })
    })
    ->whereHas('products')
    ->get();
```

Basically the query in the with will only get the products that have the attributes.

Useful information:

- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: I was able to get this working after a couple syntax fixes (will edit when the edit queue clears), but it is still returning every product group, just some of them have an empty product relationship and the others have the correct products. Is there a way to just get the ones with the correct products?